# How do I measure time in C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, time

I want to find out for how long (approximately) some block of code executes. Something like this:

```
startStopwatch();
// do some calculations
stopStopwatch();
printf("%lf", timeMesuredInSeconds);
```

How?

Comment: @Pmod What do you mean by platform? My OS is Windows.

Comment: What resolution do you want to achieve, and how much accumulated overhead are you willing to tolerate?

Comment: @Noah, I can tolerate an error of one millisec

Comment: A millisecond is a long time. Most any software clock will be good enough.

Comment: For Unix systems, see [`clock()` precision in `<time.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8594277/15168).

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can use the `clock` method in [time.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/)

Example:

```
clock_t start = clock();
/*Do something*/
clock_t end = clock();
float seconds = (float)(end - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Comment: +1: Nice and simple. However, won't you need to cast `(end - start)` to a floating point before the division if you want to get fractions of a second?

Comment: @torak Yes, I think you're right, I haven't had a chance to test it though.

Comment: Note that `clock()` measures CPU time, not wall-clock time (this may or may not be what you want).

Comment: @caf While true on Linux, clock() actually computes wall-clock time on Windows: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4e2ess30.aspx

Comment: @undefined: Not just Linux, it's actually the C standard that says *"The `clock` function determines the processor time used."*.  I suppose on Windows you can simply say that the implementation's best approximation to processor time used is wall-clock time used.

Comment: Note : For anybody confused CLOCKS_PER_SEC is NOT your cpu's clock frequency.

Comment: what the heck is a "CLOCKS_PER_SEC". this is not the right answer

Answer (score 26):

You can use the [time.h](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/) library, specifically the [time](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/time/) and [difftime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/difftime/) functions:

```
/* difftime example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
  time_t start,end;
  double dif;

  time (&start);
  // Do some calculation.
  time (&end);
  dif = difftime (end,start);
  printf ("Your calculations took %.2lf seconds to run.\n", dif );

  return 0;
}
```

(Example adapted from the difftime webpage linked above.)

Please note that this method can only give seconds worth of accuracy - `time_t` records the seconds since the [UNIX epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29#Notable_epoch_dates_in_computing) (Jan 1st, 1970).

Comment: This gives only seconds precision. And your example actually doesn't use the `<ctime.h>`.

Comment: Sorry, the 'c' was a typo - the ctime library is defined in `time.h`. And yes, it gives only seconds accuracy. Considering the poster said "approximately", I considered that enough. I will edit my answer to include the fact that it will only give seconds level of accuracy, if you wish.

Answer (score 7):

Sometime it's needed to measure **astronomical time** rather than **CPU time** (especially this applicable on **Linux**):

```
#include <time.h>

double what_time_is_it()
{
    struct timespec now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
    return now.tv_sec + now.tv_nsec*1e-9;
}

int main() {
    double time = what_time_is_it();
    printf("time taken %.6lf\n", what_time_is_it() - time);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It gives much better precision than clock()! But it is worth to mention that just including time.h was not sufficient for me. I had to link the executable with `-lrt`.

Answer (score 6):

The standard C library provides the `time` function and it is useful if you only need to compare seconds. If you need millisecond precision, though, the most portable way is to call `timespec_get`. It can tell time up to nanosecond precision, if the system supports. Calling it, however, takes a bit more effort because it involves a struct. Here's a function that just converts the struct to a simple 64-bit integer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <time.h>

int64_t millis()
{
    struct timespec now;
    timespec_get(&now, TIME_UTC);
    return ((int64_t) now.tv_sec) * 1000 + ((int64_t) now.tv_nsec) / 1000000;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("Unix timestamp with millisecond precision: %" PRId64 "\n", millis());
}
```

Unlike `clock`, this function returns a Unix timestamp so it will correctly account for the time spent in blocking functions, such as `sleep`. This is a useful property for benchmarking and implementing delays that take running time into account.

Comment: It should be added that [*C11* is required](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/chrono/timespec_get) for this.

Answer (score 3):

GetTickCount().

```
#include <windows.h>
void MeasureIt()
{
    DWORD dwStartTime = GetTickCount();
    DWORD dwElapsed;

    DoSomethingThatYouWantToTime();

    dwElapsed = GetTickCount() - dwStartTime;

    printf("It took %d.%3d seconds to complete\n", dwElapsed/1000, dwElapsed - dwElapsed/1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For sake of completeness, there is more precise clock counter than `GetTickCount()` or `clock()` which gives you only 32-bit result that can overflow relatively quickly. It's [QueryPerformanceCounter()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/profileapi/nf-profileapi-queryperformancecounter). `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` gets clock frequency which is a divisor for two counters difference. Something like `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` in <time.h>.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
    {
    LARGE_INTEGER tu_freq, tu_start, tu_end;
    __int64 t_ns;

    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&tu_freq);
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&tu_start);
    /* do your stuff */
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&tu_end);

    t_ns = 1000000000ULL * (tu_end.QuadPart - tu_start.QuadPart) / tu_freq.QuadPart;
    printf("dt = %g[s]; (%llu)[ns]\n", t_ns/(double)1e+9, t_ns);

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644904(VS.85).aspx) and [QueryPerformanceFrequency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644905(VS.85).aspx) functions of the Windows API. Call the former before and after the block and subtract (current − old) to get the number of "ticks" between the instances. Divide this by the value obtained by the latter function to get the duration in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need fantastic resolution, you could use GetTickCount(): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724408(VS.85).aspx
(If it's for something other than your own simple diagnostics, then note that this number can wrap around, so you'll need to handle that with a little arithmetic).

QueryPerformanceCounter is another reasonable option.  (It's also described on MSDN)