# Call function periodically without using threads and sleep() method in c

Tags: c

I want to call a function, lets say every 10 or 20 seconds. When I searched, I came up with threads and `sleep()` method everywhere.

I also checked for time and clock classes in C but I could not find anything helpful specific to my question.

What is the most simple way to call functions periodically?

Comment: Simple search found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557221/how-do-i-measure-time-in-c).

Comment: Why are you ruling out threads / sleep? This sounds like a "I want to do 'X' but without doing [insert good way to to 'X']" question.

Comment: The simplest way is `while(1) { sleep(10); function(); }`, so you should specify what's wrong with `sleep` (for the requirement "not to use sleep" we have plenty of alternatives doing essentially the same thing).

Comment: It depends on your system and available libraries. What are you using?

Comment: You talk of methods and classes. Are you sure you have a C problem and not a C++ problem?

Comment: I think checking now and again time passed is just the same as sleep() or even worse.

Comment: You might like ot read here: http://linux.die.net/man/2/alarm on how to setup a signal to be sent to your process after a certain amount of time. Then read here http://linux.die.net/man/2/signal on how to setup a signal handler. But be aware there that are limitations on what functions a signal handler may call. Regarding the latter please read here: http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal

Comment: Simpler?  How much simpler can you get than a Sleep() loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `libevent`, in my opinion, is the cleaner solution because, in the meantime, you can do other operations (even other timed functions)

look at this simple and self explaining example that print out Hello every 3 seconds:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <event.h>

void say_hello(int fd, short event, void *arg)
{
  printf("Hello\n");
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  struct event ev;
  struct timeval tv;

  tv.tv_sec = 3;
  tv.tv_usec = 0;

  event_init();
  evtimer_set(&ev, say_hello, NULL);
  evtimer_add(&ev, &tv);
  event_dispatch();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have the error: event.h: No such file or directory, what should I do ,do you think?

Comment: you have to install libevent and link it during the compile phase

Comment: It seems this `say_hello()` only run once in my OS, CentOS6.5-32bit.

Comment: Does libevent create another thread for the signal handler? Or is it handled within the same thread?

Comment: This doesn't work with long executing function after the event_dispatch or even recursive infinite loop for anyone that is searching a way to exit such conditions within a thread.

Comment: The code above is in error and will only call 'hello' once.  You need lines like ... struct event_base *global_base; event_assign(&ev, global_base, -1, EV_TIMEOUT|EV_PERSIST,
            say_hello, NULL); to replace the 'evtimer_set' call.

Answer (score 4):

Most operating systems have a way to "set an alarm" or "set a timer", which will call a function of yours at a given time in the future. In linux, you'd use `alarm`, in Windows you'd use `SetTimer`.

These functions have restrictions on what you can do in the function that gets called, and you almost certainly will end up with something that has multiple threads in the end anyway - although the thread may not be calling `sleep`, but some `wait_for_event` or similar function instead.

Edit: However, using a thread with a thread that contains:

```
while(1) 
{
   sleep(required_time); 
   function(); 
}
```

The problem is solved in a very straight forward way to solve the problem, and makes it very easy to handle.

Comment: +1, and with alarm/setitimer you get all "joys" of async-signal-safety restriction, so there's not much that this function could do if this method is used.

Answer (score 1):

A naive solution would be something like this:

```
/* Infinite loop */
time_t start_time = time(NULL);
for (;;)
{
    time_t now = time(NULL);

    time_t diff = now - start_time;

    if ((diff % 10) == 0)
    {
        /* Ten seconds has passed */
    }

    if ((diff % 20) == 0)
    {
        /* Twenty seconds has passed */
    }
}
```

You might want a flag that tells if the function has been called, or it will be called several times during the single second `(diff % 10) == 0` is true.

Comment: This has the drawback of "missing" if the time capture isn't happending every second (at least). Say for example if we have user input...

Comment: This won't work on implementations where `time_t` is a floating point type because `%` needs integer operands.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Of course. I _do_ state it's a naive solution. :)

Comment: @Jens I've never ever encountered a platform where `time_t` is _not_ an integer, and it's unlikely that I (or most programmers) ever will.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg So you make assumptions, which are the mother of all screw-ups. I work in the space business where GPS time may very well be fractional. We'd have our ass kicked if we were to excuse a lost satellite or launch vehicle with "I've never encountered and thought it unlikely that ..." All that counts is the spec. The spec for time_t is "a real type" (C11) or "arithmetic type" (C99).

Comment: @Jens Even when working in "space business" is `time_t` a type capable of handling the requirements and precision you need, or do you use types and APIs better suited for that problem space and let `time_t` be the traditional integer? Also, while making assumptions may be bad, if none are to be made then programming would be a couple of magnitudes harder and very few would be able to do it (think back to the age of programmers wearing white lab coats in big computer rooms).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I'll never understand why people keep defending their unreliable and unportable programming, especially in the face of existing Standard C functions to compute time differences. Even if you assume time_t is integral, you can't assume it counts seconds. To compute time differences the Standard C `difftime()` must be used. As for hardness, **programming properly is hard, it's an engineering profession**, programming junk is easy, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while(true) {
   if(System.getNanotime % 20 == 0) {
      myFunction();
   } 
}
```

This is in Java-Syntax, i didn't program c since more than 5 years, but maybe it helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    while(1)
    {
        usleep(20000) ;
        printf("tick!\n") ;
    }
}
```

Note that usleep() will of course block :)

Comment: Won't compile because <stdbool.h> is missing. Why are people so obsessed with while(true) or while(1) when a simple for(;;) would do?

Comment: Fixed. It's a matter of taste, after all.

Comment: Everybody with a taste for constants in boolean expressions needs a taste reevaluation :-) My lint flags them, rightfully. They're ugly as hell.

Answer (score 0):

The most accurate solution in my tests from from the following code#include

```
<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/timerfd.h>

void *
say_hello()
{
    int rc, fd;
    struct itimerspec myitime;
    int64_t buffer;

    fd = timerfd_create(CLOCK_REALTIME, 0);

    // every 3 seconds
    myitime.it_interval.tv_sec = 3;
    myitime.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    // start at NEXT full second
    rc = clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &(myitime.it_value));
    myitime.it_value.tv_sec += 1;
    myitime.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;

    rc = timerfd_settime(fd, TFD_TIMER_ABSTIME, &myitime, NULL) ;

    // wait for input from fd, then print hello
    while(true) {
    read(fd, &buffer, 8);
    printf("Hello\n");
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main()
{
    say_hello();
    // never returns
    return 0;
}
```

Of course say_hello can be spawned as a thread.

The timerfs call, on my unloaded system produces a printer output with a 5.3 microsecond RMS variation.   The evtimer method produces a output with a 319 microsecond RMS variation.