# How to wake a C++ 11 thread periodically?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I would be grateful for some pointers on how to wake a C++ 11 thread periodically (say every 100ms). The platform is Linux and the language C++. I came across this solution:

[C++ 11: Calling a C++ function periodically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425772/c-11-calling-a-c-function-periodically)

but there they call a callback function and then sleep for the timer interval. That means that the actual period is the function execution time + the interval. I want to call the callback at a constant interval, irrespective of its execution time.

I wonder if Boost would help? But I would prefer not to use it, as this project is not multi-platform and I want to minimize the use of third party libraries.

Perhaps combining a POSIX timer with a C++ thread is a way forward? I'm not sure exactly how that would work.

Any suggestions as to how to get started would be appreciated.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832139/call-function-periodically-without-using-threads-and-sleep-method-in-c

Comment: This is possibly what you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37240834/how-can-we-make-a-loop-with-chronicle-statement-in-c/37241412#37241412

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a good article on this topic:
Periodic Processing With Standard C++11 Facilities
https://bulldozer00.com/2013/12/27/periodic-processing-with-standard-c11-facilities/

Comment: Links can die, so it's better to paste the relevant section in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, that link looks very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

Use [`std::this_thread::sleep_until()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until), incrementing the absolute wakeup time by the fixed interval each time.

Answer (score 3):

You need to measure the time your function take to execute and then sleep for the period less the execution time. Use [std::this_thread::sleep_for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for) to sleep for that amount of time that elapsed. Eg:

```
const auto timeWindow = std::chrono::milliseconds(100);

while(true)
{
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    do_something();
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    auto elapsed = end - start;

    auto timeToWait = timeWindow - elapsed;
    if(timeToWait > std::chrono::milliseconds::zero())
    {
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(timeToWait);
    }
}
```

NOTE: If your compiler supports it you can use `100ms` rather than `std::chrono::milliseconds(100)`. Mine doesn't :-(

Comment: OP states that `do_something` duration should be part of the `100ms`.

Comment: This is what the OP wants to avoid. They want a constant interval.

Answer (score 2):

For a pure C++ approach, without any implementation-specific functions, you can create a `std::mutex` and a `std::condition_variable`, lock the mutex, then use `wait_for()` to sleep on the conditional, for 100ms, or any other interval, in your thread.

For a more precise control over wake-up intervals, that takes into account the actual time your thread takes to execute, between pauses, use `wait_until()`, together with a suitable clock.

Answer (score 1):

I would call the function via `std::async` on a timer.  However if your function regularly takes longer than the period you will rapidly consume resources.  Also creating a new thread has a relatively expensive cost.

So you could time the duration length of the function via `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` and then use `wait_for` to sleep the rest of the period.