# how to schedule a c function to run exactly every minute

Tags: c, pthreads, scheduled-tasks

I have a thread that i have created using pthread should be run exactly every minute . How can I do this in c program to run it every minute.sleep doent solve my problem .

Comment: where is the code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call function periodically without using threads and sleep() method in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14832139/call-function-periodically-without-using-threads-and-sleep-method-in-c)

Comment: Read [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html) then think a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming<sup>(a)</sup> you mean `sleep` is no good because if you sleep for 60 seconds following a seven-second job, that won't be every minute.

So, in order to go every minute regardless of how long the job takes, you can use something like (pseudo-code):

```
def threadFn():
    lastTime = now()  # or now() - 60 to run first one immediately.
    do forever:
        currTime = now()
        if currTime - lastTime >= 60:
            lastTime = currTime
            doPayload()
        sleep one second
```

This of course has the shortcoming that, if your job takes more than a minute, the next iteration of it will be delayed. But, short of having to handle multiple concurrent jobs, that's probably best.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> That seems the most likely possibility to me but it's an assumption I probably needn't have made if you'd included the code and/or added detail as to *why* it was a problem :-)

As another possibility, to ensure it only runs at `hh:mm:00` (i.e., exactly on the minute switch-over), you could do a slight variation:

```
def threadFn():
    lastTime = now() - 1 # Ensure run at first hh:mm:00.
    do forever:
        currTime = now()
        currSec = getSecond(currTime) # using C's localtime()
        if currSec == 0 and currTime != lastTime:
            lastTime = currTime
            doPayload()
        sleep one tenth of a second
```

The reduced sleep is to ensure you run the payload as quickly as possible after entering the new minute.

Comment: the thread is trying to post some data to re server .. so there may delay in that function .. regardless of that i need to post data exactly at next minute when the seconds hand of the clock turns 00.