# Shared Memory vs Named Pipe comparison gone wrong: pipe is faster?

Tags: c, posix, ipc, shared-memory, named-pipes

I have taken a course related to IPC in POSIX around 1.5 years ago and we made a benchmark to compare two communication method of 1.named pipes and 2.shared memory(with a circular buffer).

We create integers to transfer, then implement semaphores to start-stop data transfer. The repo is [here](https://github.com/EbruBaglan/ARP-HW2_IPC_benchmark) for detailed description and the code.

I know by several sources that the result should show shared memory to be faster. Even though I used a circular buffer, no matter how much I increase the buffer size(even to the same size as the total transferred size), the named pipe seems faster. However it should not be that way. Any idea why? Below are the codes.

I would also appreciate any programming practice-wise suggestions/feedbacks.

Thank you.

```
// SHARED MEMORY WITH CIRCULAR BUFFER
// command line takes KB input,
//
// for 100 MB array and 4 KB buffer, use the command line of:
// ./shared 102400 4
//
// To compile and run this code for 100 MB with 4 KB buffer, type following on the terminal
// gcc -Wall -o shared shared.c -lrt -lpthread && ./shared 102400 4

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/wait.h> // CLOCK_REAL_TIME
#include <time.h>     // CLOCK_REAL_TIME

#define CLOCK_REALTIME 0

void error_prompt(char *error_msg)
{
    perror(error_msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

double what_time_is_it()
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557221/how-do-i-measure-time-in-c/3557272
    struct timespec now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
    return now.tv_sec + now.tv_nsec * 1e-9;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // argument number should be at least 3, program name, message size and buffer size
    if (argc < 3)
    {
        perror("Please enter BOTH message size AND BUFFER CBSIZE. For instance ./shared 102400 4 \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // buffer size should not be higher than message size
    if (atoi(argv[2]) > atoi(argv[1]))
    {
        perror("Buffer size cannot be bigger than message size. Enter for instance ./shared 102400 4  \n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    double start_time_init = what_time_is_it();

    int MSGSIZE, CBSIZE, erre;
    int sizeofint = 4; // bytes
    int flag, counter;

    CBSIZE = atoi(argv[2]) * 1024;                  // circular buffer size, KB changed to bytes here
    int max_num_int_each_time = CBSIZE / sizeofint; // MAX number of integers used in each cycle

    MSGSIZE = atoi(argv[1]) * 1024;                         // message size, KB input changed to bytes here
    int num_int_total = MSGSIZE / sizeofint;                // how many integers used in total
    int num_cycles = num_int_total / max_num_int_each_time; // how many cycles in total

    int remainder = MSGSIZE % CBSIZE / sizeofint; // remainder in number of integers
    if (remainder != 0)
        flag = 1;

    // SEMAPHORE VARIABLES
    sem_t *sem1; // First semaphore
    sem_t *sem2; // Second semaphore

    /* name of the shared memory object */
    const char *semname1 = "/JakePeralta";
    const char *semname2 = "/AmySantiago";

    // create, initialize semaphores
    if ((sem1 = sem_open(semname1, O_CREAT, 0644, 1)) == SEM_FAILED)
        error_prompt("sem1");

    if ((sem2 = sem_open(semname2, O_CREAT, 0644, 0)) == SEM_FAILED)
        error_prompt("sem2");

    // end of SEMAPHORE VARIABLES

    int *arr1, *arr3;

    // allocating area on HEAP. Why? CUZ STACKOVERFLOW!!!!!
    if ((arr1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_int_total)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("arr1 malloc error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((arr3 = malloc(sizeof(int) * num_int_total)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("arr3 malloc error\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // assigning TOTAL messages here to arr1
    for (int k = 0; k < num_int_total; k++)
    {
        arr1[k] = rand() % 1000;

        // checking first and last 3 integers and middle index to make sure
        if (k < 3 || k == num_int_total / 2 || k > num_int_total - 4)
        {
            printf("Sent Index%d is %d\n", k, arr1[k]);
        }
    }

    /* name of the shared memory object */
    const char *name = "/littlespoonalltheway";

    /* shared memory file descriptor */
    int shm_fd;

    /* pointer to shared memory object */
    int *ptr;

    /* create the shared memory object */
    if ((shm_fd = shm_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666)) == -1)
        error_prompt("shm open");

    /* configure the size of the shared memory object, absence causes Bus error */
    if (ftruncate(shm_fd, CBSIZE) == -1)
        error_prompt("ftruncate");

    /* memory map the shared memory object */
    if ((ptr = mmap(0, CBSIZE, PROT_WRITE | PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0)) == MAP_FAILED)
        error_prompt("mmap");

    pid_t child_pid = fork();

    double start_time_send = what_time_is_it();

    switch (child_pid)
    {
    case -1:
        error_prompt("fork");

    case 0:
        /* child process */

        /* arr1 is seperated to chunks of max_sendable_numbers */
        for (counter = 0; counter < num_cycles; counter++)
        {
            sem_wait(sem1); // lock the semaphore
            memcpy(ptr, arr1 + counter * max_num_int_each_time, CBSIZE);
            sem_post(sem2); // release the semaphore lock
        }
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            sem_wait(sem1); // lock the semaphore
            memcpy(ptr, arr1 + counter * max_num_int_each_time, remainder * sizeofint);
            sem_post(sem2); // release the semaphore lock
        }

        free(arr1);

        /* unmap the shared memory object */
        if (munmap(ptr, CBSIZE) != 0)
            error_prompt("munmap");

        break;

    default: // case 1 ... __INT_MAX__
        // parent process

        for (erre = 0; erre < num_cycles; erre++) //
        {
            sem_wait(sem2); // Lock the semaphore
            memcpy(arr3 + max_num_int_each_time * erre, ptr, CBSIZE);
            sem_post(sem1); // Release the semaphore lock
        }

        // once more for the last remaining items
        if (flag == 1)
        {
            sem_wait(sem2); // Lock the semaphore
            memcpy(arr3 + max_num_int_each_time * erre, ptr, remainder * sizeofint);
            sem_post(sem1); // Release the semaphore lock
        }

        printf("---\n");
        printf("Received Index0 is %d\n", arr3[0]);
        printf("Received Index1 is %d\n", arr3[1]);
        printf("Received Index2 is %d\n", arr3[2]);
        printf("Received Index%d is %d\n", num_int_total / 2, arr3[num_int_total / 2]);
        printf("Received Index%d is %d\n", num_int_total - 3, arr3[num_int_total - 3]);
        printf("Received Index%d is %d\n", num_int_total - 2, arr3[num_int_total - 2]);
        printf("Received Index%d is %d\n", num_int_total - 1, arr3[num_int_total - 1]);

        double finish_time = what_time_is_it();
        printf("---\n\n");
        printf("SHARED MEMORY WITH CIRCULAR BUFFER\n\n");
        printf("User requested to transfer TOTAL OF %d KB = %d MB with %d KB buffer.\nData is transferred as integers. The size of integer is %d bytes.\n", MSGSIZE / 1024, MSGSIZE / 1024 / 1024, CBSIZE / 1024, sizeofint);
        // printf("Total of %d cycles were required with a number of %d integers transferred, with each cycle having %d integers. \n\n", num_cycles, num_int_total, CBSIZE / 4);
        // printf("%d cycles should have been completed. Check..\n\n", num_cycles);
        printf("\nTime calculated for transfers:\n");
        printf("Since the start-up of processes : %.6lf seconds, \n", finish_time - start_time_init);
        printf("Since the start-up of send      : %.6lf seconds. \n", finish_time - start_time_send);
        printf("\n---\n\n");
        free(arr3);

        /* remove the shared memory object */
        if ((shm_unlink("/littlespoonalltheway") != 0))
            error_prompt("unlink");

        /* close and unlink semaphores */
        if (sem_close(sem1) != 0)
            error_prompt("sem_close1");

        if (sem_unlink(semname1) != 0)
            error_prompt("sem_unlink1");

        if (sem_close(sem2) != 0)
            error_prompt("sem_close2");

        if (sem_unlink(semname2) != 0)
            error_prompt("sem_unlink2");

        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code for the named pipes is below.

```
// NAMED PIPE
// command line takes KB input,
//
// for 100 MB array, use the command line of:
// ./named 102400
//
// To compile & run this code for 100 MB, type following on the terminal 
// gcc -Wall -o named named.c && ./named 102400

#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/stat.h> // mkfifo

int flag = 0;

void error_prompt(char error_msg[], int status)
{
    if (status < 0)
    {
        perror(error_msg);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

double what_time_is_it()
{
    // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3557221/how-do-i-measure-time-in-c/3557272
    struct timespec now;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &now);
    return now.tv_sec + now.tv_nsec * 1e-9;
}

void my_handler(int signum)
{
    if (signum == SIGUSR1)
    {
        flag = 1;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // initiate part--------
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        perror("Please enter the size of the array in KB");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int size_of_array = atoi(argv[1]) * 1024 / sizeof(int);

    int fd1, fd2;
    int sizeofint = 4;
    int ret;
    sighandler_t res;
    pid_t child_pid;

    char *myfifo = "/tmp/myfifo5";
    if ((ret = mkfifo(myfifo, 0666)) != 0)
        error_prompt("mkfifo failed", ret);

    int *a;

    if ((a = (int *)malloc(size_of_array * sizeof(int))) == NULL)
    {
        printf("malloc error \n ");
        exit(1);
    }

    // assign random number to the array
    for (int i = 0; i < size_of_array; ++i){
        a[i] = rand() % 1000;
        if (i < 3 || i == size_of_array / 2 || i > size_of_array - 4)
        {
            printf("Sent Index%d is %d\n", i, a[i]);
        }
    }

    double start_time_init = what_time_is_it();

    if ((child_pid = fork()) == -1)
        error_prompt("fork failed", child_pid);

    else if (child_pid == 0)
    {
        // child process
        if ((fd2 = open(myfifo, O_RDONLY)) < 0)
            error_prompt("fd2", fd2);

        int *buffer = (int *)malloc(size_of_array * sizeof(int));
        int n = 0;
        int remaining = size_of_array;
        int i = 0;
        while (remaining != 0)
        {
            if ((n += read(fd2, buffer + i, 65536)) < 0)
                error_prompt("read failed", n);

            i += 65536/4;

            if ((ret = kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1)) != 0)
                error_prompt("kill failed", ret);

            remaining -= 65536/4;
            if (remaining < 0)
                remaining = 0;
        }

        //printf("\nReceived, first value = %d, last value = %d\n", buffer[0], buffer[size_of_array - 1]);

        printf("---\n");
        printf("Received Index0 is %d\n", buffer[0]);
        printf("Received Index1 is %d\n", buffer[1]);
        printf("Received Index2 is %d\n", buffer[2]);
        printf("Received Index%d is %d\n", size_of_array / 2, buffer[size_of_array / 2]);
        printf("Received Index%d is %d\n", size_of_array - 3, buffer[size_of_array - 3]);
        printf("Received Index%d is %d\n", size_of_array - 2, buffer[size_of_array - 2]);
        printf("Received Index%d is %d\n", size_of_array - 1, buffer[size_of_array - 1]);

        free(buffer);

        if ((ret = close(fd2)) == -1)
            error_prompt("close fd2 failed", ret);

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        // parent process
        if ((fd1 = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY)) < 0)
            error_prompt("fd1", fd1);

        // printf("\nPipe size: %d bytes = %d KB\n", fcntl(fd1, F_GETPIPE_SZ), fcntl(fd1, F_GETPIPE_SZ) / 1024);

        if ((res = signal(SIGUSR1, my_handler)) == SIG_ERR)
            error_prompt("signal", ret);

        int remaining = size_of_array;

        int i = 0;

        double start_time_send = what_time_is_it();

        while (remaining != 0)
        {
            if ((ret = write(fd1, a + i, 65536)) < 0)
                error_prompt("write failed", ret);

            i += 65536/4;
            remaining -= 65536/4;

            if (remaining < 0)
                remaining = 0;

            while (flag == 0)
                pause();
            flag = 0;
        }

        free(a);

        wait(NULL);

        double finish_time = what_time_is_it();
        
        printf("---\n\n");
        printf("NAMED PIPE\n\n");
        printf("User requested to transfer TOTAL OF %d KB = %d MB with %d KB named pipe capacity.\nData is transferred as integers. The size of integer is %d bytes.\n", atoi(argv[1]), atoi(argv[1]) / 1024, fcntl(fd1, F_GETPIPE_SZ) / 1024, sizeofint);
        printf("\nSo an integer array of %d elements is created and sent successfully.\n", size_of_array);
        printf("\nTime calculated for transfers:\n");
        printf("Since the start-up of processes : %.6lf seconds, \n", finish_time - start_time_init);
        printf("Since the start-up of send      : %.6lf seconds. \n", finish_time - start_time_send);
        printf("\n---\n\n");

        if ((ret = close(fd1)) == -1)
            error_prompt("close fd2 failed", ret);

        if ((ret = unlink(myfifo)) == -1)
            error_prompt("unlink failed", ret);

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I expected shared memory method to be faster than the named pipe.

Comment: *I know by several sources that the result should show shared memory to be faster.*  What OS is being used in those sources?  What specific version of that OS?  What hardware?  How many CPUs might be critical.  **When** were those sources written?  Spectre and Meltdown mitigations significantly increased the cost of system calls in Linux and your pipe implementation doesn't need to use semaphores, which require more system calls to pass data.  See [**Disable Spectre and Meltdown mitigations**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/554908/disable-spectre-and-meltdown-mitigations)

Comment: The `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()` operations are not particularly cheap, especially when the semaphore is shared between processes.  With the pipe, the kernel is doing the synchronization for you.

Comment: Aside from `sem_wait/sem_post` being slow, you have only _one_ shared memory buffer. I recommend a [reusable] pool of such buffers. I've done commercial implementations of fast interprocess/interthread transfers using shared memory buffers (for video compression/decompression). Instead of `sem_*`, I've used `msgsnd/msgrcv`. See my answer: [In C, is storing data in local variables in threads akin to creating a local copy? AKA Does this Threadpool synchronization make sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75762865/5382650). There, it has a `void *work_data;` field. Point that to a shared buffer

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54164058) is a benchmark where there is a massive difference with my results. From the statistics of the repo and how people refer to this repo, I found that more trustworthy than mine.

In this case, does that mean I should have used another method than semaphores and this would result in the similar way?